# Unable to install ionic app in ios device

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, ionic-framework

I have built an ionic 4 application that runs fine on android and ios both but when I am trying to make a production build .ipa file is generated but it is not installing in ios device. I have tried to generate .ipa from both `ionic cordova build ios --prod` and XCode Archive. I have added service extension for push notifications which is causing a problem because if I build without the extension it runs fine.

I am not getting where I am doing a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve this by selecting a Generic iOS device instead of connected device.
it was a silly mistake and wasted 4 hours